# Creating object with ManyToMany field via DRF ViewSet's perform_create

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a simple model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  user = ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_items")
  users = ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_items")
```

I want it so that when a user creates an `Item` via ViewSet, that user is automatically assigned to the `user` and `users` fields.

I typically do this for ForeignKey's via the ViewSet's perform_create:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  ...
  
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
      serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    else:
      serializer.save()
```

When I try to do it for the ManyToManyField too, I get this error:

```
{'users': [ErrorDetail(string='This list may not be empty.', code='empty')]}
```

I've tried the following in perform_create():

```
# 1
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, users=self.request.user)
# 2
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, users=[self.request.user])
# 2
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, users=[self.request.user.id])
```

How can I update a ManyToManyField via a ViewSet's perform_create?

**Edit:**

I guess the following works:

```
obj = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
obj.users.add(self.request.user)
```

Is there no way to have the M2M field when the object is initially created though?

Answer (score 0):

when you want set a list to m2m field one of the things you can do is this:

```
item_obj.users.set(user_list)
```

probably you need first get your item_obj.
for this you can get your object id from `item_id = serializer.data.get('id')` , and then  `item_obj = Item.objects.get(id = item_id)`